# Convergence of Operator Values implies Convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, uniform-convergence

Consider a bounded operator $T:C(X)\to C(X)$ in the sense that $\Vert Tf \Vert_{\infty}\leq C \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}$. Consider $z\in \rho(T)$ (i.e. $(T-z)^{-1}$ exists) and a bounded sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(T-z)f_n\to g \in C(X)$. Is there a short way to show $f_n\to (T-z)^{-1}g$? I think this is used in the proof I want to use, but I have problems finding a good argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. The operator $(T-z)^{-1}$ is closed because $T-z$ is, and therefore it is bounded by the closed graph theorem. Hence
$$
f_n=(T-z)^{-1}(T-z)f_n\to (T-z)^{-1}g.
$$

Comment: Sorry that I have to take back the "acceptance", but I had some follow up questions afterwards. I only know closed operators on Banach space, but $C(X)$ is not complete. How would you define a closed operator here? And how do you obtain the closedness from the boundedness?

Comment: If $X$ is compact (as I suppose it is in thise case, otherwise the supremum norm is not necessarily finite for all continuous functions), then $C(X)$ is complete. And boundedness is clearly a stronger condition than closedness for operators on a Banach space. This is immediate from the definition.